# Twilio Sip Dial for incoming call

Tags: java, sip, twilio, pbx

I'm using the Twilio Java API and I can't seem to build a response that will dial a Sip extension.

```
TwiMLResponse twiml = new TwiMLResponse();
Sip sip = new Sip("xxx@xxx.com");
Dial dial = new Dial();

try {
    dial.append(sip);
    twiml.append(say);
    twiml.append(dial);
}
```

The above code throws the exception "This is not a supported verb" when I get to dial.append(sip)

How do you nest Sip inside of Dial?
Or How do I dial a Sip number?
I need this to route my incoming calls.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. Its:

```
Dial dial = new Dial(sip.toXML());
```